# Directed Graph Shortest path source to destination Dijkstra

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

Here is my code to get the shortest path

```
static void shortestPath(int[][] adjacencyMatrix,  int src, int dest) { 
    int n = adjacencyMatrix[0].length; 
    int[] shortest = new int[n]; 
    boolean[] added = new boolean[n]; 
    for (int v = 0; v < n;v++)  { 
        shortest[v] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
        added[v] = false; 
    } 
    shortest[src] = 0; 
    int[] parents = new int[n]; 
    parents[src] = NO_PARENT; 

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)  { 
        int v1 = -1; //store temp data
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
        for (int v = 0;  v < n;  v++) { 
            if (!added[v] &&  shortest[v] < min) { 
                v1 = v; 
                min = shortest[v]; 
            } 
        } 
        added[v1] = true; // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)  { 
            int dist = adjacencyMatrix[v1][v];                  
            if (dist > 0 && ((min + dist) <shortest[v])){ 
                parents[v] = v1; 
                shortest[v] = min + dist; 
            } 
        } 
    }  
    dists.add(shortest[dest]);
    visitUtil(dest, parents); 
} 

static void visitUtil(int i,int[] parents)  {   
    if (i == NO_PARENT)         
        return; 

    visitUtil(parents[i], parents);             
    edges.add(i);
}
```

My matrix is this

```
        { 0,10, 0, 0, 3 },
        {0, 0, 5, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 7, 8 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Here is my graph so you can see it.

[image]

I get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. For example, lets say I want to go from 2-4, in the graph below, you can see that the weight is 8, and they are directly attached.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't seem to use loopcounter `i`? Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: @rsp I updated my question. It wasn't worded right and I put in TWO exceptions... not the one I actually needed help with. I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds at added[v1] = true;

Comment: In your 1st pass both `shortest[v]` and `min` are equal to `MAX_VALUE`, so `v1 == -1` at the exception point. (not using `i` at all still seems a problem)

Comment: The algorithm was made from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-paths-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/.

Comment: Run through it in a debugger a few times to get a feel of what happens and to check that against your expectations of it.

Comment: yeah it doesnt seem to be "connecting" the nodes. If the nodes are connected, itll work, at long as it starts at 0. ive been running through debugger for awhile trying to figure it out. only reason why I posted here. lol